# Adjusting the 3D game to the screen size

Tags: unity-game-engine

How to make the 3D game adapt to the screen resolution?

I tried to change the fieldOfView of the camera, but this adjustment does not work correctly!

Comment: adapt the game? adapt the screen resolution? or adapt camera view? there are 3 different questions ^^'

Comment: Adapt the game to different screen resolutions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean UI elements, there are little triangles usually in the middle of the canvas the element is under. These are anchors that will tell the element to try and stay in the same place on the canvas regardless of the screen resolution. You can read more about it here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIBasicLayout.html https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html

If you mean your actual game view, you'd probably need to write a script that adjusts the camera's FOV at the start of the game based on the resolution, but I have no idea where to even begin on the formula you'd use.